# Как уместить содержимое в AlertDialog (Android OS)?

Tags: android, java, разметка

Задача: вывести диалог, содержащий текст и список с тремя пунктами на выбор. Текст пунктов и предваряющий текст диалога слишком большой по количеству символов. Таким образом, требуется либо добавить горизонтальную полосу прокрутки, либо уменьшить размер текста элементов диалога.

Как реализовать хоть один вариант из видимых? Методов для управления параметрами текста для объектов класса Dialog нет. В подключаемом файле разметки, также не вижу явно решений, т.к. пункты списка добавляются программно, а по сути неизвестно, это TextView'ы или что-то иное.

Пробовал добавить HorizontalScrollView следующим образом:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#F00B">

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/horizon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">           
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/lin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Я предполагаю, что все содержимое располагается где-то между тегами `<LinearLayout>`, `</LinearLayout>`. На деле, по запуску приложения, по нажатии кнопки выводится диалог без каких-либо полос прокрутки. Вообщем, выходит такое:

[image: снимок эмулятора]

Answer (score 1):

А почему горизонтальная прокрутка?

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#F00B">
      <ScrollView>
         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

         ...

         </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: 2Vitozz
Текст пунктов списка не вмещается именно по длине. По ширине все ок.